# UIImage doesn't fade in/out when blur is on

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiviewanimation, uiblureffect

I have `UIImage` which is blurred like this:

```
myImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageSet[0])
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
        blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView?.frame = view.bounds
        myImageView.addSubview(blurEffectView!)
```

and then I want to fade in new UIImage like this:

```
UIView.transitionWithView(self.backgroundImageView,
        duration:1.0,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve,
        animations: { self.myImageView.image = UIImage(named: self.imageSet[randomInt]
        },
        completion: nil)
```

and the problem is, new image simply appears, rather than fade in. If I disable blur, images fade in and out. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You add your `blurEffectView` as a subview of `myImageView` but you can not change alpha or give animation to `UIBlurEffect` nor `UIVisualEffectView`. Instead of that, add new `UIView` with same frame and constraints as your `imageView` object then add your effects as a subview of a `UIView` object ;

```
myImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageSet[0])
let animationView = UIView(frame: myImageView.bounds)
animationView.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style:.Light))
blurEffectView?.frame = animationView.bounds
view.addSubview(animationView)
animationView.addSubview(blurEffectView!)
```

Comment: I was adding `blurEffectView` to `myImageView` because in my UIView I have `UIView` in front of `myImageView`. Now, you method works, but since I am adding blurr to `UIView`, that view is being blurred as well. Any ideas, how to bring that one view in front of blurred image, that fades in/out?